# How do you align a local scaling along a global coordinate

Tags: bones, edit-mode, scale

I have a bone. I am scaling it's tail along its local y-axis, and I want the tail to be located at the global z=0 while the x and y coordinates can vary. The problem is if I type in 0 in its z coordinate, it only shifts up, not along its local y axis. 
How can I shift something along its local axis such that it meets the global coordinate z=0?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. Created armature, entered edit mode, selected tail, pressed S to scale, but since only the tail was selected, nothing scaled.

Comment: Adding some images and clearly stating what you want to achieve would help... . Your description is really unclear, please apply more effort if you really need an answer.